# Getting a function to run everytime a jquery mobile page is loaded

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to get a function to run everytime jquery mobile loads a new page into the application, but currently, the code only gets run once on the first instance of a page loading.

HTML:

```
<div id="pageID" data-role="page" class="content_page">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="bestHeader" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- end header -->
    <section data-role="content">
        <h2>Header2</h2>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
    </section>
<div class="bottomAd" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <img src="ad2.jpg" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="bestFooter" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
     <!-- navBar here -->   
        </nav> 
    </div><!-- end footer -->        

</div><!-- end page -->    

  <div id="pageID2" data-role="page" class="content_page">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="bestHeader" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- end header -->
    <section data-role="content">
        <h2>Header2</h2>
            <p>Content goes here</p>
    </section>
<div class="bottomAd" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <img src="ad2.jpg" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-id="bestFooter" data-position="fixed">
        <nav data-role="navbar">
     <!-- navBar here -->   
        </nav> 
    </div><!-- end footer -->        

</div><!-- end page -->
```

Javascript

```
$(".content_page").live('pageinit', function(event) {
    if ($(".bottomAd img[src*=ad]").length >= 1) {
        console.log($(".bottomAd img[src*=ad]").length);
        $(".bottomAd").remove();
    }
```

No matter how many times you click back and forth between the two pages, the console.log only gets called once, and the .bottomAd class gets removed document wide on the first instance of the page getting clicked on. I'd like to have the function run everytime the page is called, so each time the "page" is checked for having an image with a src that contains "ad" in the bottomAd div on that specific page, and then removed if so.

Comment: Use `pageshow` instead of `pageinit`

Comment: Okay. I understand now. It's removing the div .bottomAd from both pages when the first page is loaded, and thus, there was no div with an img[src*=ad] on the second page when it gets called. Is there a way where I can have the code check just the page that is loaded for a div containing img[src*=ad], and if so, remove the div from only that page?

Comment: @JohnHancock See my answer, I propose a suggestion for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do work on something each time a page is shown (either the first time or subsequent visits) then I suggest using `pageshow`, `pageinit` only fires the first time a page is shown and jQuery Mobile will keep pages in the DOM sometimes. If you want to run some code only the first time a user goes to a page then use `pageinit` but bind your delegated event handler to the `document` element.

I would also make your selector more specific (to the current page) so you don't work on elements on pages not being viewed like so:

```
...
//`this` refers to the `<data-role="page">` pseudo-page element being bound to
$(this).find(".bottomAd").remove();
..
```

Your delegated event handler should bind to an element always in the DOM, for example `document`:

```
$(".content_page").live('pageinit', function(event) {
```

should be

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '.content_page', function () {...});
```

Note that `.live()` was depreciated in jQuery 1.7 and that `.on()` is the new flavor.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a ton. One question though: pageshow still has the div displayed as the page transitions in, and then when it finishes the transition, the div removes. Anyway to prevent seeing this unwanted div using pageshow if pageinit is not preferable here?

Comment: @JohnHancock Here are all the events you can use: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html. I think you're looking for `pagebeforechange`.

Comment: Appreciate the link. pagebeforechange wasn't removing the div, but pagebeforeshow got it done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `pageshow` event, you also might want to use [.on](http://www.bing.com/search?q=jQuery%20On%20Function&FORM=QSRE3) instead of `.live` as `.live` is depreciated,

For example

```
$(document).on('pageshow','.content_page' function(event) {
    if ($(".bottomAd img[src*=ad]").length >= 1) {
        console.log($(".bottomAd img[src*=ad]").length);
        $(".bottomAd").remove();
    }
```

There is also a [pageload](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html) event but that is fired when an external page is attached to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

pageload Event

"Triggered after the page is successfully loaded and inserted into the DOM. Callbacks bound to this event will be passed a data object as its 2nd arg. "

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html